# How to make a loop or funciton to select needed data in R? My data is stored as a list

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 13 dataframes stored in a list called mysheets that I imported with readxl

This is how each dataframe looks like (each sheet is named after the year of data)

```
Year    Category   Count 
2009    Yellow     23
2009    Black      23
2009    Blue       45
2009    Blue       12
```

```
Year    Category   Count 
2010    Yellow     45
2010    Orange     24
2010    Blue       56
2010    Blue       13
```

And so on.

If I wanted to get a new dataframe with a sum of of all "blue" categories per year.

So my desired output would be

```
Year   Category   Count
2009    Blue      57
2010    Blue      69
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to loop over the `list` of data.frames with `map`, `filter` the rows where 'Category' is 'Blue' (assuming only a single year dataset per `list`), get the `first` of 'Year', 'Category' and the `sum` of 'Count' in `summarise`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_dfr(mysheets, ~ .x %>%
                   select(Year, Category, Count) %>%
                   filter(Category == 'Blue') %>%
                    summarise(Year = first(Year), Category = first(Category),
                              Count = sum(Count))
```

---

Or bind the dataets together, then do the `filter` and a group by `sum`

```
bind_rows(mysheets) %>%
      filter(Category == 'Blue') %>%
      group_by(Year) %>%
      summarise(Category = first(Category), Count = sum(Count))
```

Comment: Which is best practice? I've been told that binds are computationally heavy and take long.  Especially since I may have to this multiple times for different categories?

Comment: @FruityPebblePug If the datasets are very big, then it may be better to `filter` it with `map` which will reduce the size first and memory load would be less

Comment: I see that the with the first function I am selecting all the columns, how can I specify only Year, Category and count?

Comment: @FruityPebblePug you can add `select` at the top.  updated